# "data-" prefix is added to custom attributes, how to prevent this?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have upgraded Pandoc to v2, and some of my regression tests fail now.

It's the ones where I add custom attributes to elements like so:

```
# Test {role="heading" aria-level="7"}
```

In earlier versions of Pandoc, this resulted in

```
<h1 role="heading" aria-level="7">Test</h1>
```

While in Pandoc 2, it's

```
<h1 data-role="heading" data-aria-level="7">Test</h1>
```

How can I change it back? Both `role` and `aria-` attributes are 100% valid HTML, so no `data-` prefix is needed.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Maybe this will work? https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/MANUAL.txt#L1906

Comment: I think this may be a feature, in that HTML5 wants all custom attributes to begin with data- to distinguish them from HTML5 attributes.  According to that spec, those custom attributes with a data- prefix are then by definition ignored by the renderer.

Comment: @moilejter beat me to it, I just found that myself and updated my answer. The OP will need to use Pandoc's 'html4' conversion method or adapt to the new behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a difference with Pandoc in the conversion from Markdown to HTML5 vs HTML4.

Using their test editor the HTML4 conversion works perfectly fine.

[Pandoc HTML4 Conversion Example](https://pandoc.org/try/?text=%23%20Test%20%7Brole%3D%22heading%22%20aria-level%3D%227%22%7D&from=markdown&to=html4)

However, when we switch to HTML5 the data- portion of the attribute gets injected.

[Pandoc HTML5 Conversion Example](https://pandoc.org/try/?text=%23%20Test%20%7Brole%3D%22heading%22%20aria-level%3D%227%22%7D&from=markdown&to=html5)

This makes me think that this is either intentionally done, for differences between HTML4 and HTML5, or that it is potentially a Pandoc bug, which you should probably raise an issue with them in their github issue tracker:  https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues

From the Pandoc docs - html defaults to html5 as follows:

> - `html` or `html5` ([HTML], i.e. [HTML5]/XHTML [polyglot markup])
> - `html4` ([XHTML] 1.0 Transitional)

---

**Update:**

It looks like this IS because of HTML5 spec - the "role" and "aria" attributes themselves are no longer in the attribute list. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

So this **NOT** a bug with Pandoc - this is expected behavior. My suggestion, use the html4 conversion is your answer.

Thanks to @Caramiriel in the comments for additional reference in the [Pandoc code](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/9752dcd61aa72a9e1e59bafcd55376ab1d275620/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs#L576).

Comment: Reference in source: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/9752dcd61aa72a9e1e59bafcd55376ab1d275620/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/HTML.hs#L576

Comment: @Caramiriel thanks, that certainly clarifies that this is expected behavior from Pandoc.

Comment: `![](img.svg){align="center"}` generate `<img src="img.svg" data-align="center" />`. Why `data-align` and not `align`?

Comment: @HNoob while it looks like align is still support in HTML5 - many consider it to be a legacy attribute and better defined in CSS, perhaps the Pandoc developers felt best to leave align out?  Have you used HTML4 conversion instead because that seems to work fine.